# Use template in Azure pipeline for repository refs

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a project with multiple repositories and I would like to use a specific branch to checkout for RepoB, that matches the target branch of the PR

```
name: My nice pipeline
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: RepoB
      type: git
      name: RepoB
      # ref: ${{ replace($(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch), "refs/heads/", "")}}  <<<< here is the issue
```

And the issue is that if I use just a plane $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch) the input is accepted but the way ref: works, it will append to refs/heads/{{whatever the input was here}}, so I end up having refs/heads/refs/heads/target-branch. As a solution I though I can use replace but yeah thanks not the case...

Any ideas how I can grab just the target branch name without the prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `System.PullRequest.TargetBranch` in template expression (which is `{{}}`). You have marked it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

[image]

And I can't find it at the moment, but from what I recall you can't use template expression in repository resource.

This is unfortunately not possible. You can't use expression here.
[image]

And if you try use this syntax `ref:$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)`, you will get

> /azure-pipelines-11.yml: Could not get the latest source version for repository kmadof/devops-templates hosted on https://github.com/ using ref refs/heads/$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch). GitHub reported the error, "No commit found for SHA: refs/heads/$(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)"

Comment: So how do I remove the unnecessary refs/heads/ from the $(System.PullRequest.TargetBranch)  is there a way to do it at all?

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't parameterized repository resource.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you when I wanted to create a tag on a branch and specific commit in my pipeline. The best solution I found was just to make my agent do all the parts I would normally do and put it in a template :p this is how I solved it.

```
  steps:
- checkout: none
  clean: True

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Remove refs/heads from branch path and set pipeline variable
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $branchSourcePath = "$(Build.SourceBranch)" -replace "refs/heads/",""
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=BRANCH_PATH;]$branchSourcePath"
      Write-Host "Setting pipeline variable BRANCH_PATH to $branchSourcePath"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Create temp folder
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'New-Item -Path "$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp" -ItemType Directory'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Init git repo
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'git init'
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Git remote add
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: git remote add $(Build.Repository.Name) https://$(git-accesstoken)@{azure-repo-path}/_git/$(Build.Repository.Name)
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Fetch
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'git fetch $(Build.Repository.Name) $(BRANCH_PATH)'
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Checkout commit
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "Checking out commit $(Build.SourceVersion) \n"
      git checkout -b $(BRANCH_PATH) $(Build.SourceVersion)
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set user email
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: git config --global user.email "$(Build.RequestedForEmail)"
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Set user name
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: git config --global user.name "$(Build.RequestedFor)"
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Create tag
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'git tag -a {tag-name} $(Build.SourceVersion) -m "{tag-description}"'
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Push tag'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'git push {repo-name} {tag-name}'
    workingDirectory: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\temp'

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: Delete temp folder
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
    Contents: 'temp'
```